# Angular2 and Facebook SDK FB.ui dialog closed after clicking next

Tags: angular, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-live-api

I'm trying to implement Facebook live using Facebook [Go Live Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/exploring-live#golivedialog) on an angular2 apps. 
I have the SDK working and it makes api calls ok, but when trying to use FB.ui the dialog is not woking well because the dialog's first screen appears and ask where to publish, but when clicking on Next, the dialog dissapears and I have no feedback about what happens.
(clicking next should show another dialog with the 2nd step)

Any hints to work on this?

facebooklive.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FacebookService, FacebookLoginResponse, FacebookInitParams, 
FacebookApiMethod} from 'ng2-facebook-sdk/dist';

@Component({
...
template : '<button (click)="FBDialog()">Dialog</button>'
providers: [...FacebookService]
})
export class Facebook_live implements OnInit {
constructor(private fb:FacebookService) {
let fbParams:FacebookInitParams = {
appId: 'xxxxx',
xfbml: false,
version: 'v2.8'
};
this.fb.init(fbParams);
}

FBDialog() {
 this.fb.ui(
    {
        display: 'popup',
        method: 'live_broadcast',
        phase: 'create',
    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);

        if (!response.id) {
            console.log('dialog canceled');
            return;
        }
        console.log('stream url:' + response.secure_stream_url);

        this.fb.ui(
            {
                display: 'popup',
                method: 'live_broadcast',
                phase: 'publish',
                broadcast_data: response,
            },
            function (response) {
                console.log("video status: \n" + response.status);
            });
    });


}
```

**Edit 1:** Angular-cli says
Webpack is now Valid

but after a few seconds appears:
[default] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

I checked FB SDK for fb.ui and it only ask for 2 params: `FB.ui(params, function(response))` and I'm giving it both.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the ES6 [arrow function `=>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) otherwise you won't be able to use `this` inside a function.
2. The [ng2-facebook-sdk](https://github.com/zyramedia/ng2-facebook-sdk) `returns` a `promise` if you read the [README.md](https://github.com/zyramedia/ng2-facebook-sdk/blob/master/README.md) you will see `ui(params: FacebookUiParams): Promise`.
3. The `fb.init` inside the constructor does not need `this`

---

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FacebookService, FacebookLoginResponse, FacebookInitParams,
  FacebookApiMethod} from 'ng2-facebook-sdk/dist';

@Component({
  ...
    template : '<button (click)="FBDialog()">Dialog</button>'
    providers: [...FacebookService]
})
export class Facebook_live implements OnInit {


  constructor(private fb:FacebookService) {
    let fbParams:FacebookInitParams = {
      appId: 'xxxxx',
      xfbml: false,
      version: 'v2.8'
    };
    fb.init(fbParams);
  }

  FBDialog() {
    this.fb.ui(
      {
        display: 'popup',
        method: 'live_broadcast',
        phase: 'create',
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {
          if (!response.id) {
            console.log('dialog canceled');
            return;
          }

          console.log('stream url:' + response.secure_stream_url);

          this.fb.ui(
            {
              display: 'popup',
              method: 'live_broadcast',
              phase: 'publish',
              broadcast_data: response,
            }).then(
            (response) => {
            console.log("video status: \n" + response.status);
          },
          (error: any) => console.error(error)
          );


      },
      (error: any) => console.error(error)
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: you are right, but it still don't work. it seems that the function's callback isn't triggered, I click NEXT and the dialog closes without feedback.

Comment: Just looked at the ng2-facebook-sdk API and it returns a promise, I'll update the code.

Comment: @CristianSepulveda I've updated my answer with the problems I've found and the corrected code.

Comment: great, now using promises the dialog works and shows the 2nd step, but ng-cli shows a new error: `Argument of type '{ display: string; method: string; phase: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FacebookUiParams'.` reading **ng2-facebook-sdk** 's readme there is no specification for **FacebookUiParams**. also I still can't get the response value, I need **response.secure_stream_url** that should come in the response.

Comment: Where did you read that you should use that object in the fb.ui call? I can see that the docs don't have any such code. Where did you get the code from in the first place?

Comment: in the Go Live Dialog: [link] (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/exploring-live#golivedialog)

Comment: Can you run `npm list ng2-facebook-sdk` and tell me what version you have installed?

Comment: I'm just submitting a pull request with the updates needed to the interface you can manually add these until they accept the commit.

Comment: You can see the pull request here https://github.com/zyramedia/ng2-facebook-sdk/pull/33 and the committed changed here https://github.com/zyramedia/ng2-facebook-sdk/pull/33/commits/15da634f58eab70b915e661e3f1ff94e1a63c44a

Comment: so fast!!! I changed the interface locally and it works, now there is no error. but I still can't catch any response data :/ (I'm using ng2-facebook-sdk@1.0.0. )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131079/discussion-between-j-j-b-and-cristian-sepulveda).